# Pass a set of Array to a new function for computing

Tags: c

It generates error.

```
  int main(void)
  {
     int Numbers[9]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
     printf("%i\n", SUM(Numbers[9]));
  }

  int SUM(int array[int n])
  {
     int sum = array[1]*2 + array[2]*3 + array[3]*4 + array[4]*6 + array[5]*6;
     return sum;
   }
```

It says i have passed too many arguments to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passing one `int` by `Numbers[9]`. You need to pass the array by passing the pointer to it. But actually a 1D array name is practically the pointer to the first element of the array. This will fix it:

```
  int main(void)
  {
     int Numbers[9]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
     printf("%i\n", SUM(Numbers)); // passing the pointer to the array
  }

  int SUM(int array[]) // int SUM(int *array) would also work
  {
     int sum = array[1]*2 + array[2]*3 + array[3]*4 + array[4]*6 + array[5]*6;
     return sum;
  }
```

Note that usually you want to pass the size too so you can check bounds and thus avoiding over indexing the array.

Comment: Nearly; an array name _decays_ to the pointer to the first element in _some cases_. In others, it doesn't (for example when calling `sizeof array`)

Comment: @Ctx Yes indeed it is more accurate to say that.